# Combining datetime (with time component) and time objects

Tags: python, datetime

Well, I have datetime objects with information like **2013-10-01 14:15:00** and time objects like

1. **1900-01-01 00:00:49.235000**
2. **1900-01-01 00:00:49.465000**
3. **1900-01-01 00:00:49.695000**

The time objects are actually progressive increments which I'd like to add to the datetime object. As described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine),

> If date is a datetime object, its time components and tzinfo attributes are ignored.

I wrote the code below. How should it be updated to be able to add these time objects to the datetime object as increments?

```
def CombineDateTime(date_str, time_str, date_fmt, time_fmt, equipment, sample_name):

import datetime

try:
    date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, date_fmt)

    time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_str, time_fmt)

    return datetime.datetime.combine(date_obj.date(), time_obj.time())

except:
    return 'Error'
```

Output:

1. **2013-10-01 00:00:49.235000**
2. **2013-10-01 00:00:49.465000**
3. **2013-10-01 00:00:49.695000**

Expected output:

1. **2013-10-01 14:15:49.235000**
2. **2013-10-01 14:15:49.465000**
3. **2013-10-01 14:15:49.695000**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output that you get is because `2013-10-01` and `00:00:49.235000` to your datetime.datetime.combine() and the time present in date_obj `14:15:00` is not taken into consideration at that point!

Therefore, you have the add the date_obj timedelta to your time_obj before you combine!

```
date_time=date_obj.time()
time_obj += datetime.timedelta(hours=date_time.hour,minutes=date_time.minute,seconds=date_time.second,microseconds=date_time.microsecond)
```

That is,

```
def CombineDateTime(date_str, time_str, date_fmt, time_fmt, equipment, sample_name):
    import datetime
    try:
        date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, date_fmt)
        date_time=date_obj.time()

        time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_str, time_fmt)
        time_obj += datetime.timedelta(hours=date_time.hour,minutes=date_time.minute,seconds=date_time.second,microseconds=date_time.microsecond)

        return datetime.datetime.combine(date_obj.date(),time_obj.time())

    except Exception as e:
        #print e 
        return 'Error'
```